# Determining cosets of representatives

Tags: modular-forms

Is there an algorithm to determine the cosets of representatives of a congruence subgroup of a modular form? I know what cosets of representatives and when given a set, I know how to check that they are cosets. However, what I'm asking is for the converse. Does it also get more difficult if I'm restricting the matrices that I get to one that gives me a connected fundamental domain?